# rails 5 using devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

hi currently i am making a new project using rails 5, and devise , my problem is that i am trying to get the current user that is logged into my webapp, and then get the current users id and save it into the database.

currently getting a lot of error and having trouble doing so.

my database are the following for the sample

Note this is the default devise setup for the user

```
User
    username
    password
    email address

blog
    title.text
    body.text
    user_id.integer
```

now my problem is that how do i get the current user that is logged into my webapp, and then save it into the blog database that contains the user_id. i havent added the blog yet into one of my samples , but i am currently failing at the results that i need to be making and pushing forward into it.

is there a way to scaffold it , or do i need to go commando and hardcode it, if so how is it possible to do so?

1. get the current user so that it gets the current user id and save it to each blog.
   2.how do i push it into the controller
2. how do i do it into the model as well

i am a bit confused as to how it should be made and done , with rails any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your user.rb model**
define relationship with user in this way

```
has_many :blogs
```

in your bolg.rb model

```
belongs_to :user
```

now in your create method in your blog controller

`@user = current_user`

then

```
if @user.blogs.create(blog_params)
  #your logic
end
```

This automatically save user_id to database.